# The mayor has decided to build an amusement park because it (would/will) attract many tourists

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Is "would" correct in the following? If so, how does it differ from "will"?

> The mayor has decided to build an amusement park because it **would** / **will** attract many tourists.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**would** and **will** are both correct. There is no stringent syntactic rule that *requires* a backshift from **will** to **would** inasmuch as the second clause can be considered so-called *reported* speech.

Some stylists might regard **will** as lacking in felicity and clarity, but it's grammatical.  With **will** it's not perfectly clear whether the author is asserting that the amusement park will indeed attract many tourists or is only presenting the mayor's argument.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are correct, but depending on the scenario, one or the other might be preferable.

In your sentence, where the mayor **has decided**, I would use **will**, because it is a definite, and not a proposal.

However, if you changed the sentence to say the mayor **is considering**, you would probably use **would** because it is referring to something that may or may not happen.

"The mayor is considering building a new amusement park, because [if he builds it,] it would attract many tourists."

However, using the sentence as it stands, I would use *will*, because the mayor has *already* decided to build it, and it's just what is going to happen.

If this helped, please **upvote** (up arrow next to question) and **mark as accepted** (checkmark below upvote)